Asymptotic expansion of the solution of a nonlinear wave equation
I am reading the article Recovery of a cubic non-linearity in the wave equation in the weakly non-linear regime (arXiv link) by Barreto, Plamen, where they consider the modified cubic NLWE
$$-\partial_{tt} u + \Delta u = \alpha(x) u|u|^2$$
with $\alpha\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d), \alpha \ge 0$ and initial data at time $t_0=-R-\delta$ of the form $h^{-1/2} e^{i(x\cdot \omega-t_0)/h}\chi(t_0-x\cdot \omega)$ with $\chi$ smooth and compactly supported with the goal of recovering the coefficient $\alpha(x)$ ($h>0$ is small).
The authors assume a solution $u(x,t)$ of the form
$$u=h^{-1/2}e^{i(x\cdot\omega-t)/h} a(x,t,h),$$
with
$$a(x,t,h)=a_0+ha_1+h^2a_2+\ldots.$$
They then substitute this expansion into the wave equation and obtain a hierarchy of equations for $a_0, a_1, \ldots$ which they solve. A this point, they remark that after solving a finite number $N$ of these equation, they obtain a solution $u_N $satisfying
$$-\partial_{tt} u_N + \Delta u_N - \alpha(x) u_N|u_N|^2=R_N=O_{H^s}(h^{N-1/2-s})$$
in the $H^s_x$ norm. Presumably, we have
$$u_N=\sum_{j=0}^N a_j h^j.$$
Question 1: What do the authors mean when they write $a(x,t,h)=a_0+ha_1+h^2a_2+\ldots$? Is it a formal asymptotic expansion?
Question 2: Why can they assume such an expansion exists?

The link given in this post requires a login. Here is an alternative: https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06323

Thank you for commenting the arxiv link. I have added it to the post.

1: Yes. Even if the authors didn't, you can think of it that way. 2: It's a standard hypothesis. If the expansion is obstructed at some order, then it doesn't exist. If it is never obstructed, then it does exist.

Are there conditions that guarantee such an expansion to exist? What confuses me is that the authors do not explicitly mention this hypothesis in their theorems and treat it as if it is guaranteed to hold.

concerning 1: the authors mention that they are looking for an asymptotic expansion at the start of section 2.

Fair point. Maybe they don’t put that as an assumption in their theorems because it is implicitly understood beyond Section 2. I am still interested in the second question.
